# Oracle LTRIM triming too many charecters

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to use LRTIM to obtain part of a string.

This is the code that I am using.

```
SELECT
C.MANUFACTURER,
C.MODEL_GROUP,
LTRIM(C.VARIANT, C.MANUFACTURER || ' ' || C.MODEL_GROUP), "VAR DESC"
C.VARIANT
FROM STD_BI.RL2_CONTRACTS_VW C
```

This is what I have field wise

```
VARIANT
AUDI A3 DIESEL SPORTBACK 2.0 TDI SE Technik 5dr Manual 150

MANUFACTURER 
AUDI

MODEL_GROUP
A3
```

This is the result that I am getting

```
MANUFACTURER  MODEL_GROUP   VAR DESC

AUDI          A3            ESEL SPORTBACK 2.0 TDI SE Technik 5dr Manual 150
```

It is cutting off the first 2 characters of DIESEL, the problem is that this is not happening in all cases. Sometimes it is cutting off 1 character and sometimes none!

I have considered other methods of achieving this, i.e. looking for the spaces,  but have other manufacturers and model groups that have multiple spaces so was trying to subtract the MANUFACTURER and MODEL_ROUP from the VARIANT field (string)

Any ideas as to why this might be happening or other suggestions for achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Keith

Apologies seems like the editor is reformating the results that I am getting

[Oracle query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkdzY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` with `'^'` - Indicating start of string.

```
SELECT
C.MANUFACTURER,
C.MODEL_GROUP,
REGEXP_REPLACE(C.VARIANT, '^'||C.MANUFACTURER || ' +' || C.MODEL_GROUP) "VAR DESC",
C.VARIANT
FROM STD_BI.RL2_CONTRACTS_VW C
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to LTRIM is a set of single characters, not a sequence of characters. In your example the database removes characters from the left until it encounters the first character not in ('A','U','D','I','A','3'), which is the `E` of `DIESEL`.

In order to remove a prefix `p` from a string `s` use something like

```
case when SUBSTR(s,1,LENGTH(p))=p then SUBSTR(s,LENGTH(p)+1) else s end
```

which in your case expands to

```
case when SUBSTR(C.VARIANT, 1, LENGTH(C.MANUFACTURER || ' ' || C.MODEL_GROUP))
          =                           C.MANUFACTURER || ' ' || C.MODEL_GROUP 
     then SUBSTR(C.VARIANT, 1+ LENGTH(C.MANUFACTURER || ' ' || C.MODEL_GROUP))
     else s 
end
```